# Are there any identities linking arithmetic functions and $\pi$?

Tags: arithmetic, pi

The question is self-explainatory.

For example are there any known identities involving Euler Totient function and $\pi$ ?

Comment: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_totient_function#Other_formulae_involving_.CF.86):
$$
\sum_{k= 1}^n\varphi(k) = \frac{3n^2}{\pi^2} + O\left(n(\log n)^{2/3}(\log\log n)^{4/3}\right)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several identities of this kind. Here are just some examples:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}, \; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^4}=\frac{90}{\pi^4},\; \ldots ,
$$
where $\mu(n)$ denotes the Moebius $\mu$-function;
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sigma(1)+\cdots \sigma(n)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12},
$$
where $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum of divisor function;
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\phi(1)+\cdots \phi(n)}{n^2}=\frac{3}{\pi^2},
$$
where $\phi(n)$ denotes Euler's $\phi$-function.

Answer (score 1):

*Sterling formula* for finding limit is another example that utilizes pi. And to make your question more " appealing " you might want to add another ingredient like e and states it like this: " list all possible identities and approximations that involve either pi or e or both constants "

Answer (score 1):

If $f(n)$ ($n=1,2,3,\ldots$) is the number of ways that $n$ can be written in the form $n=a^2 + b^2$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, then there is a very nice fact about the average value of this function:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(1)+f(2)+\cdots + f(n)}{n} = \pi$$

Mysterious, or obvious?  I'll leave that up to you.